# Обновить значение свойства .value созданного IMask

Tags: javascript

Не могу достучаться до  свойства .value в Imask.

```js
 function showMask(id, name, placeholder) {
        let element = document.getElementById(id);
        let maskOptions = {}
        switch (name) {
            case 'inputCodePhone':
                maskOptions.mask = '0000';
                break;
            default:
                maskOptions.mask = placeholder;
                break;
        }
        new IMask(element, maskOptions);
    }
    
function checkSmsCode() {
                // код код код....
                    if (ajax.status === 400) {
                       inputCode.classList.add('is-invalid');
                        IMask.value = "";
                        inputCode.value = "";
                        inputCode.placeholder = 'Неверный код';
                    }
                });
            }
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Введите код из смс" id="inputCode"
name="inputCodePhone"  onclick="showMask(this.id,this.name)">
<button class="btn" type="button" onclick="checkSmsCode()">Подтвердить</button>
```

Смысл обрезанного мною фрагмента кода, что по нажатию кнопки проверяем код из смс ,используя параллельно IMask при вводе. И если код неверен, то поле станет красным, заменится inputCode.value на "" и заменится плейсхолдер. Но если начать вводить повторно, вылезет ошибка и ввод кода становится невозможным:

> Element value was changed outside of mask. Syncronize mask using `mask.updateValue()` to work properly.

Суть ее понятна и видел решения в интернетах, но они не работают, потому что я не знаю, как в моем случае "обнулить" .value у объекта Imask

Comment: Решил проблему путем использования регулярки не трогая IMask. Но для общего развития интересно было бы узнать решение с IMask

Comment: стоит все же почитать про ооп. вы у класса пытаетесь засетить статическое поле по сути. попробуйте присвоить экземпляр класса переменной и повызывать у переменной методы.